# Alarm clock in C

Tags: c, clock, alarm

The code runs perfectly until it prints xx.00.00 which it prints twice. All the other code runs without a problem but each time goes from 23.59.59 -) 00.00.00 it gets printed twice. PLEASE HELP ME

```
#include <stdio.h>
void check(int number) {
    if (number < 10) {
        printf("0%d", number);
    }
    else {
        printf("%d", number);
    }
}
void count(int present_time, int time_for_alarm) {
    int present_hour = present_time/10000;
    int present_min = (present_time/100) % 100;
    int present_sec = (present_time % 100);
    int alarm_hour = time_for_alarm/10000;
    int alarm_min = (time_for_alarm/100) % 100;
    int alarm_sec = (time_for_alarm % 100);
    while (present_hour != alarm_hour) {
        if (present_hour == alarm_hour && present_min == alarm_min && present_sec == alarm_sec) {
            printf("ALARM");
        }
        else {
            if (present_sec <= 60) {
                present_sec++;
                if (present_sec == 60) {
                    present_sec = 0;
                    present_min++;
                }
                if (present_min == 60) {
                    present_min = 0;
                    present_hour++;
                }
                if (present_hour == 24) {
                    present_hour = 0;
                }
                check(present_hour);
                printf(":");
                check(present_min);
                printf(":");
                check(present_sec);
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
    }
    while (present_min != alarm_min) {
        if (present_hour == alarm_hour && present_min == alarm_min && present_sec == alarm_sec) {
            printf("ALARM");
        }
        else {
            if (present_sec <= 60) {
                present_sec++;

                if (present_sec == 60) {
                    present_sec = 0;
                    present_min++;
                }
                check(present_hour);
                printf(":");
                check(present_min);
                printf(":");
                check(present_sec);
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
    }
    while (present_sec != alarm_sec) {
            check(present_hour);
            printf(":");
            check(present_min);
            printf(":");
            check(present_sec);
            printf("\n");
        present_sec++;
    }
}
int main() {
    int present_time, time_for_alarm;
    printf("What time is it? (HHMMSS)");
    scanf("%d", &present_time);
    printf("What time should the alarm go off? (HHMMSS)");
    scanf("%d", &time_for_alarm);
    count(present_time, time_for_alarm);
    printf("ALARM");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your loops strike me as odd. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Your check function will become unneeded once your read the documentation of printf again. It offers printing with specified and padded width.

Comment: I see three places where you print something. Change the ":" to other characters so that you can always tell which output comes from where. I bet you will find that the unexpected two outputs come from different loops.

Comment: This:

 `while (present_hour != alarm_hour) {
        if (present_hour == alarm_hour && present_min == alarm_min && present_sec == alarm_sec) {
            printf("ALARM");
        }`
is a problem because by definition inside your while loop present_hour will always be different from alarm_hour, thus code inside your if condition will never execute

Comment: Unrelated: instead of `check(hour); printf(":"); ...` use `printf("%02d:%02d:%02d", hour, min, sec);`

Comment: Does not get printed twice for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue is right here:

```
while (present_sec != alarm_sec) {
        check(present_hour);
        printf(":");
        check(present_min);
        printf(":");
        check(present_sec);
        printf("\n");
    present_sec++;
}
```

In every other loop, you advance `present_sec` first, then print the time.  In this loop, you advance after.  When you reach the correct hour and minute, you enter this loop, and you will always duplicate the time here.  Try inputting 225555 and 225605.  You will see 22:56:00 duplicated.